# How to compare month and year from Date column data table in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my data table have `Date` column and what I enter `txtmonth Textbox and txtyear textbox`. I need to compare my data table of `Date` column in month and year to `txtmonth and txtyear textboxes` if they are equal message `valid`.

My code

The above code I did like it's compare single record but I need to check all records at a time, how can I do this?

Comment: You will get better response if you add some code, that you are trying, also be specific about your problem

Comment: are talking about JQuery or C# or SQL Server ? Please provide more details , so i can help you .

Comment: Maybe something like `var DateField = DateTime.Parse(date); if (DateField.Month.ToString() == txtMonth.Text && DateField.Year.ToString() == txtyear.Text) MessageBox.Show("valid");` , replacing `DateField` with the value from your datatable?

Comment: Hi @keyur-patel, `DateField.Month` i don't have `month and year` column in my data table i have only `Date` column only from `Date column` i need to compare month and year my `Date column like 01/27/2017` i need to compare `01 and 2017`

Comment: Hi @un-lucky, I added my code

Comment: The line `var DateField = DateTime.Parse(date);` converts your date string into a DateTime object, which can easily give you a Month and Year. Of course, if the date string is ever incorrect or null, you need some checking, best case is to use DateTime.TryParse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Ben805: Well what you are going to print on the textbox at the end of looping? is that howmany of them are valid?

Comment: Hi @keyur-patel, i don't need conversions. In my above code i did for each and every time compare single record but I need how can i compare all those rows after display valid or not messsage

Comment: Hi @un-lucky, I have `100 rows` in my `datatable` i need to compare `month and year from Date column` with `txtmonth and txtyear` if all the records are valid at last display valid

Comment: Hi I uploaded my image also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ben805

```
bool Ismatch=false;

DataTable dt = new DataTable;
            int FilteCarriercount = (from q in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   where q.Field<string>("Date").ToString().Split('/')[0] == txtmonth.Text &&
                                   q.Field<string>("Date").ToString().Split('/')[2] == txtyear.Tex
                                      select new 
                                      {
                                          date = q["Date"],

                                      }).ToList().Count;

If(FilteCarriercount >0)
{
  lblmessage("You Uploaded Valid document");
}
else
{
  lblmessage("You Uploaded is not Valid document");
}
```

Please check above code.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ronak-patel, Thank you it's working but i changed that code. In my uploaded document contains both `2017 & 2016 any row` here i am entering text boxes only 2017 if in case it comapres 2016 row also it showing all the records `Ismatch==true` at last

Comment: Hi @Ronak-patel, is it possible to take `dt.select()`

Comment: Hi @Ronak-patel, i added this  `else { Ismatch==false; break; }` it's working.Thank you

Comment: Hi @Ronak-patel, if the above code for all checking result display at last in that if any field does not match also it showing the valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool, as follows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable;
bool success = true;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string date = dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
    string[] date1 = date.Split('/');
    string month = date1[0];
    string year = date1[2];
    if (month != txtmonth.Text || year != txtyear.Text)
    {
        success = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (success)
{
    lblmessage("You Uploaded Valid document");
}
else
{
    lblmessage("You Uploaded is not Valid document");
}
```